# How to copy permissions of one Google Drive file to another file

Tags: google-drive-api

I've created a File using Google Drive API v3, when I try to copy that file, I've to copy all permission to the new file.

```
Permission newUserPermission = new Permission();
newUserPermission.setType("user");
newUserPermission.setRole("writer");
newUserPermission.setId(permissionId);
```

I'm facing an error

> An error occurred:
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400
>   Bad Request {   "code" : 400,   "errors" : [ {
>       "domain" : "global",
>       "location" : "permission.emailAddress",
>       "locationType" : "other",
>       "message" : "The emailAddress field is required for permissions of type 'user' or 'group'.",
>       "reason" : "required"   } ],   "message" : "The emailAddress field is required for permissions of type 'user' or 'group'." }

Answer (score 0):

The resolution is in the error itself. You're missing an [email address](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-permissions#types_roles_and_values_how_the_permissions_work) who you're giving the access to.

You can see this in [Permission.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create):

> **emailAddress**      The email address of the user or group to which
>   this permission refers.

[Javascript sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing#examples) using NodeJS

```
var userPermission = {
  'type': 'user',
  'role': 'writer',
  'emailAddress': 'user@example.com'
}
```